# To change the character to string

Tags: java

Have to change the character "^" to "255E"

```
String s_ysymbol = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(DBConstants.YSYMBOL));
```

in this ysymbol starting charecter will be ^ have to change it to 255E and then have to do further process..
I tried the replace method

```
s_ysymbol.replace("^","255E");
```

but it not changing.. can anybody provide solution..

Comment: Strings are immutable in Java. You need to re-assign the resultant string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this 
`s_ysymbol = s_ysymbol.replace("^","255E");`

Answer (score 1):

`replace` returns another instance of `String`, you can't modify an existing one so an assignment is required.

```
s_ysymbol = s_ysymbol.replace("^","255E");
```

Alternatively, you could use `replaceFirst` or `replaceAll` to pass a regular expression and change the first occurrence or all occurrences of it. In such case, you'd have to use an escape character.

```
s_ysymbol = s_ysymbol.replaceFirst("\^","255E");
```

Comment: No, the first argument of replace is not a regex.

Comment: @RohitJain sorry, I confused it with `replaceFirst`

Answer (score 1):

just look into the source code of class String.

```
public final class String{
....
}
```

Please pay attention to the key word final. It means that String object can't be changed. So all of the methods in class String don't change the object itself, but create new String object and return to the new object. That's why only " s_ysymbol.replace("^","255E"); " doesn't make any changes.

```
s_ysymbol = s_ysymbol.replace("^","255E");
```

this will work.